# Using openMapQuest with meteor framework

Tags: javascript, meteor, leaflet, mapquest

I'm thinking of switching my Application from leaflet to OpenMapquest.

The main reason is that i need the free routing capability of OpenMapquest,

The problem is that leaflet has a package for meteor, but OpenMapQuest has not. Is it possible to make the switch ? is it enough to just include the js files of OpenMapQuest ? Or is there a free alternative to draw routes of Leaflet ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** 
The code below only changes the tiles and does not impact routing.  See [MapQuest directions web service](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/) on how to use JavaScript to get routing data from their Route Service.

---

According to [this](http://sajjad.in/2012/01/mapquest-tiles-through-leaflet-js/) blog post, you just need to change the preamble.

> The Cloudmade maps layer looks like this.:

```
var map = new L.Map('map');
var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/API-KEY/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
cloudmadeAttrib = 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade',
cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: cloudmadeAttrib});
```

> Change the preamble to.

```
var map = new L.Map('map');
var mapquestUrl = 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    subDomains = ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4'],
    mapquestAttrib = 'Data, imagery and map information provided by <a href="http://open.mapquest.co.uk" target="_blank">MapQuest</a>, <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> and contributors.',
    mapquest = new L.TileLayer(mapquestUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: mapquestAttrib, subdomains: subDomains});
```

http://sajjad.in/2012/01/mapquest-tiles-through-leaflet-js/

Comment: This will just change the looks of the map,  it doesn't allow me to use the routing services of mapquest right?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at MapQuest.

I haven't tried this myself, but you might be able to make a request to the [Open Directions API](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/) (from your Leaflet-based app), provide a [mapState](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/#advancedparameters) with your request, and then parse the results and display the routeShape on your map.  Keep in mind I haven't tried this myself so I don't know for sure if it would work, but it may be an option for you.

Comment: I thought about it, and you're right the routing webservice sends back these info, but they're only usable in MapQuest, which is logical.
Anyway, I managed to use Mapquest with meteor without a problem. So thank you for your great work :)